# Netlify-forms Contact Form submission 404 error

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, netlify, netlify-form

I am having trouble submitting my Contact Page through using Netlify-Forms, I am getting a 404 error.

I have the following form :-

```
<form name="Portfolio_Contact" 
      method="POST" 
      data-netlify="true"
      data-netlify-honeypot="bot-field"
      action="/thank-you">
    <div className="form-group">
      <input
        type="text"
        name="name"
        placeholder="name"
        className="form-control"
      />
      <input
        type="email"
        placeholder="email"
        name="email"
        className="form-control"
      />
      <textarea
        name="message"
        rows="5"
        placeholder="message"
        className="form-control"
      ></textarea>
      <div data-netlify-recaptcha="true"></div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" className="submit-btn btn">
      send me your message
    </button>
  </form>
```

And when I submit it, I am first getting a 404 error, and then getting my thank-you page as expected.

Am I doing something wrong? I can see my “Portfolio_Contact” in the Forms section.

Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 2):

You have a reCAPTCHA set but your form is not expecting it since is not defined in your `<form>` tag. Just add:

```
<form name="Portfolio_Contact" 
      method="POST" 
      data-netlify="true"
      data-netlify-honeypot="bot-field" 
      data-netlify-recaptcha="true"
      action="/thank-you">
```

Spot the `data-netlify-recaptcha="true"`. You can find more information in [Netlify documentation for reCAPTCHA 2](https://docs.netlify.com/forms/spam-filters/#netlify-provided-recaptcha-2).

> I am getting this in the network :`- Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin`

Besides of this configuration on the `<form>` tag, you need to set up your `POST` action configuration. Netlify is kind of weird in their responses, a `404` doesn't mean that your form doesn't exist, it means that the request failed. I usually apply the exact `<form>` configuration that I've posted but I add a custom submit handle function which sets the request configurations:

```
<form name="Portfolio_Contact" 
      method="POST" 
      data-netlify="true"
      data-netlify-honeypot="bot-field" 
      data-netlify-recaptcha="true"
      action="/thank-you">
    <div className="form-group">
      <input
        type="text"
        name="name"
        placeholder="name"
        className="form-control"
      />
      <input
        type="email"
        placeholder="email"
        name="email"
        className="form-control"
      />
      <textarea
        name="message"
        rows="5"
        placeholder="message"
        className="form-control"
      ></textarea>
      <div data-netlify-recaptcha="true"></div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" className="submit-btn btn" onClick={handleSubmit}>
      send me your message
    </button>
  </form>
```

Your `handleSubmit` function:

```
  const handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

   // do your verifications and checks
   if(!verified) return false    

    const REQUEST_PARAMETERS = {
      method: `POST`,
      headers: { 'Content-Type': `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` },
      body: encode({ ...data }), //your data here. Needs to have your form-name attribute set
    };

    fetch(`/`, REQUEST_PARAMETERS)
      .then(() => {
        console.log(`OK`);
      })
      .catch(error => alert(error));
  };
```

*Note: your request won't work in your local environment*

This configuration is important because sets the headers of the request, what is failing in your sample.

You can check for a sample in this [DEV article](https://dev.to/travislramos/how-to-use-netlify-forms-with-gatsby-4c52).

Comment: unfortunately not working.  I also removed data-netlify-honeypot="bot-field" to make it look like the example but no luck at all

Comment: I am getting this in the network :- Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Comment: I added this to the form enctype="multipart/form-data" and <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="Portfolio_Contact" />, now I am getting a 303 response

Comment: Ok, this is due to the configuration of your AJAX request. I will update my answer.

Comment: Hi Ferran, i removed the data-netlify-recaptcha="true" from the <form> tag and it worked.  I am not getting a recaptcha of course, however I will do one with Google, there is an example.  This is the only way I could get it to work!